# Release.Environments.{Stage}.Status is always "InProgress"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a **release** pipeline on Azure DevOps. At the end of the pipleline (last step) it's checking the **stage** status and sending it over to another system.

I'm grabbing the status from the predefined variable: `Release.Environments.MyStage.Status`
The issue is the variable is always `InProgress` regardless of what happens during the release (failure or cancellation).

Is this by design? Is there another way to do this without having to setup multiple steps (with different conditions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the Stage status while he not finished the status will be "In Progress" because this is the current status.

The variable designed to check the status of **another** stages so when you have 2 stages, the first stage failed and in the second stage (that run after the first finished) you check his status you will get "Rejected" and not "In Progress".

If you want to check the current Stage status you can do it with the variable `Agent.JobStatus`, this variable returns the current job status (the variable appear only in the Build variables docs but he works also in the Release).